# How can I open a fixed url by a few strokes on chrome whth vimium

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On chrome I installed Awesome and Vimium, everytime when I enter "t" , the awesome page shows up. Is there some way to open a fixed url by a few keystroke, such as type "t" and open www.google.com in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to align with this issue. Helpfully, the hint given in response is a reasonable workaround in the meantime. For a more concise shortcut, using a rarely used key (eg. `for B`) as the bookmark name should help.

It's the answer I got from the plugin writer.

https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/933